# extracting digits from url

Tags: python, regex, xpath, scrapy

Trying to extract only digits from the following string on website:

```
<div class="with_basic_sprite" id="m_product_price_div"> 1111 EURO </div>
```

my xpath for that field is (there are others, working, so I don't include them here) is the following:

```
s.xpath(".//div[@id='m_product_price_div']/text()").re('^([0-9\.]+)')
```

and it doesn't work, price fields are empty.
Same with `.re('^([\d]+)')`.

tried `.extract()` and it pulls both price and currency.

Any hint where I have it wrong with regex?

Comment: there's whitespace in between your start anchor and the digits, so neither of those regex will match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex should be just:

```
([0-9\.]+)
```

Instead of:

```
^([0-9\.]+)
```

because the number that you want is not at the beginning of the string

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
s.xpath(".//div[@id='m_product_price_div']/text()").re('^\s?([0-9\.]+)')
```